# Two different android apps with GAE endpoints for the same API backend?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoint

I have an app for android that uses GAE endpoints. This application is free but I have to make a paid version with some extra features. The problem is that two different applications and would not know how to connect a second application with the same endpoints. How can I create a second android project to share endpoints of the first application and can access the same API on the backend?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a **client id for your second app** in your api console, in the same manner as your first app. Then in your endpoints backend code, modify your **endpoint annotations** to include the id for your second app in the **audience** and **client ids** list along with your first app

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understood as giving access to the api to the second application. But I have another question, how modified the App Engine project (endpoints) to generate the endpoint client library in two applications?

Comment: The only modification you do in app engine project is adding the client ids of required app and no logic change as endpoints code will be independent of your app's logic. In your 2nd android app, you need add the same endpoints library for android client to your libs folder. Also in the second app , you need to add the service methods for calling the endpoints.

Comment: @user2770828 Regarding generating the endpoint client library into two client projects - there is no good solution, at least in Ecipse (maybe cmd line or AS are better?).   So, I manually copy the generated endpoint library from one client project to the other.

Comment: @user2770828: Can you please confirm if creating the client id way worked for you?